# fastcgi_cache_path keys_zone=WPCACHE:2048m inactive=480m; disk size

Tags: nginx

I have setup a directive to cache to memdisk in nginx with:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /dev/shm/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=WPCACHE:2048m inactive=480m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
       #snip other locations...

       # Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
       location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_pass php;

          fastcgi_cache WPCACHE;
          fastcgi_cache_valid 200 480m;
          add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

          fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
          fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
          fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

          #more_clear_headers Server; more_clear_headers "Pragma";
          add_header Z_LOCATION "PHP MAIN"; add_header URI $uri; # DEBUG
    }

}
```

I understand this should **limit size of cache to 2GB for 480 minutes**, however it is now at 2.8GB so above this limit - any idea what I am doing wrong please?

```
root@www1:/dev/shm/nginx# du -sch *
182M    0
183M    1
177M    2
174M    3
177M    4
172M    5
172M    6
167M    7
174M    8
172M    9
168M    a
171M    b
174M    c
177M    d
172M    e
179M    f
2.8G    total
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keys_zone` parameter of the `fastcgi_cache_path` directive specifies a memory zone to store cache keys.  Its size indirectly limits number of items the cache can store (1 megabyte ~ 8k items), but not on-disk size of the cache.

To limit on-disk size use the `max_size` parameter:

```
fastcgi_cache_path ... max_size=2048m;
```

See [fastcgi_cache_path documentation](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_cache_path) for more details.

Comment: Many thanks online have read that "zone_size" is a size of keys_zone (to store cache keys), whereas "max_size" is a maximum size of data on disk (i.e. cache itself). If I wanted 2GB of cached files, any recommendations on how big would I need to make the cache keys size (or any rules of thumb to calculate this)?

Comment: How many memory to use for keys depends on number of resources you want to cache. When using `max_size`, something like max_size / <average response size> should be a good starting point.